# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error in program

Tags: c

I'm brand new to C and I can't figure out how to get rid of this error when passing this in console. I tried looking at the other questions, but really I have no clue what to look for. I tried looking at the passings of the argv but didn't find anything that stood out.

```
./calculate factorial 4

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Program:

```
#include "calculate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "factorial") == 0){
        int result = factorial(argc, argv);
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "combination") == 0){
        int result = combination(argc, argv);
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "permutation") == 0){
        int result = permutation(argc, argv);
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "pythagorean") == 0){
        int result = pythagorean(argc, argv);
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else{
    printf("You did not use a valid input!\n");
    }

    printf("Assignment1-4");
    return 0;
}

int factorial(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int i = atoi(argv[3]);
    if ( i == 0 ){
        return 1;
    }
    return(i * factorial((i - 1),argv));
}

int combination(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int n = atoi(argv[3]);
    int i = atoi(argv[4]);
    return(factorial(n,argv) / (factorial(i,argv) * factorial((n- i), argv)));
}

int permutation(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int n = atoi(argv[3]);
    int i = atoi(argv[4]);
    return(factorial(n,argv) / factorial((n-i), argv));
}

int pythagorean(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int c = 0;
    int a = atoi(argv[3]);
    int b = atoi(argv[4]);
    c = (a*a) + (b*b);
    c = sqrt(c);
    return c;
}
```

I just can't find the issue, thanks.

Comment: Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`   with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Your fix-my-bug question is **off-topic** on StackOverflow, and your question has no [MCVE]

Comment: what is the purpose of this program. what do you need to do ?

Comment: For what input are you getting error? Please describe your problem more completely.

Comment: `int i = atoi(argv[3]);` should be `int i = atoi(argv[2]);`

Comment: You are using `argv[3]` and `argv[4]` all over the place when you only have 0, 1 and 2 (`argv[0]` is the name of the program).  Use `argc` to check how many command-line arguments have been entered.

Answer (score 1):

In function factorial(), you assign argv[3] to i. But you don not have argv[3] entry as you run your program with `./calculate factorial 4`. That means argc is only 3 (length of argv array is 3). You are accessing argv[] array out of its range. Use `i = atoi(argv[2])` to get the intended value.

Also in recursion call, i is always initialized with argv[] value. So it will never reach 0 and result in infinite loop.

Write factorial() like below and call from main() as `factorial(atoi(argv[2]))`

```
int factorial(int i){                                                      
if ( i == 0 ){                                                              
    return 1;                                                               
}                                                                           
return(i * factorial((i - 1));                                        
}
```

Comment: And check that argc is large enough first. I recommend investing some time to learn about getopt for proper command line argument handling.

Answer (score -1):

you yield for arguments 3 and 4 but you never provide those. so there is the exception.
and here how you should implement the program

here the commands to

```
./calculate factorial 4 
./calculate combination 4 3
./calculate permutation 6 3
./calculate pythagorean 3 4
```

and here is the source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if(strcmp(argv[1], "factorial") == 0){
        int result = factorial(atoi(argv[2]));
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "combination") == 0){
        int result = combination(atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "permutation") == 0){
        int result = permutation(atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "pythagorean") == 0){
        int result = pythagorean(atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    else{
    printf("You did not use a valid input!\n");
    }
    printf("Assignment1-4");
    return 0;
}
int factorial(int i){
    if ( i == 0 ){
        return 1;
    }
    return(i * factorial(i-1));
}
int combination(int n, int i){
    return(factorial(n) / (factorial(i) * factorial((n- i))));
}
int permutation(int n, int i){
    return(factorial(n) / factorial(n-i));
}
int pythagorean(int a, int b){
    int c = 0;
    c = (a*a) + (b*b);
    c = sqrt(c);
    return c;
}
```